# PHP is connecting to AWS PostgreSQL 14.6 from local machine but not from web server

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-14

The PHP is connecting to an AWS PostgreSQL 11.5 database from the web server. It has the same VPC's as the one I am trying to connect to.

Here is the PHP code that works when connecting to the database from local machine:

```php
$db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials" );
if(!$db) {
 echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
} else {
 echo "Opened database successfully\n";
}
```

When the php is loaded from the web browser, it displays:

> "Error : Unable to open database"

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked the web server error log?

Comment: Try calling `pg_last_error($db);` to find out _why_ it failed.

Comment: pg_last_error($db); is blank, which probably means that there is no error

Comment: Also the server error logs are not giving a description of the error.

Comment: Are you manually able to connect to the database? Do inbound rules for database instances allow public access?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the database from my local machine. The inbound rules are the same as the other databases that I can connect to from online.